# pyspark.pandas.read_sql_query from postgresql on AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, pyspark-pandas

jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://"+domain+":"+str(port)+"/"+database+"?user="+user+"&password="+password+""

```
import pyspark.pandas as pd

pd.read_sql_query(select * from table, jdbcurl)
```

Giving error on AWS Glue

[image: AWS Glue Error image]

Any suggestion??

Official Documentation :

[https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.read_sql_query.html](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

any suggestion to solve the above mentioned problem

Comment: Why are you not using `spark.read.format("jdbc").option(...).load()` ?

Comment: Because I want to use the pyspark.pandas.read_sql_query() and If i am able to do that Then I can save a lot of time changing other similar codes